# Cross-Browser animated gif on hover & reverse when mouse leaves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following images:

[**Static Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Kgi.png) | [**Starting Animation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14qMg.gif) | [**Ending Animation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwJ0.gif)

And I am using the following code ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yL5hbzxq/3/)):

```js
$(function() {
    $("#link-gif").hover(
        function() {
            /* starting animation */
            $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/14qMg.gif')");
        },
        function() {
            /* ending animation */
            $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwJ0.gif')");
        }                         
    );                  
});
```

```css
#link-gif {
   width:150px;
   height:40px;
   border:1px solid #39464E;
   background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Kgi.png'); /*static*/
   background-size:contain;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:bottom center;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="link">
  <div id="link-gif">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

So in summary, what I want to happen is: I first load the static image. When someone hover's over the `#link-gif`, the starting animation gif starts, and when you hover off of it, the ending animation starts.

For some reason, when you hover over the image, the image doesn't animate. It just goes to the end of the gif. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: You can't really control animated gifs in any browser.

Comment: @adeneo Well I am just trying to successfully show an animated gif on hover. I mean anything is possible right? ;)

Comment: Works perfectly for me

Comment: @Turnip it worked perfectly for me at first, but then if I came back to the jsfiddle, it stopped working and kept going to the end of the animation.

Comment: Ah, yes. The snippet works fine but not on JSFiddle

Comment: That's caching for you, does this work the way you wanted -> https://jsfiddle.net/yL5hbzxq/6/

Comment: @adeneo it appears to work. Any reason why this works and my example doesn't?

Comment: There's a bug in most browsers that has been present for almost two decades, it's probably gone so far as it's no longer a bug, but a "feature", where cached animated gifs set as background in CSS are not restarted when reloaded, they always stay at the end of the animation. Apparently it has something to do with caching interference (server headers, HTTPS etc) with the animation framework most browser use. As noone really uses animated gifs anymore, expect [Ling](http://lingscars.com), it's probably not an issue that is going to be fixed.

Comment: @adeneo wow good to know. I appreciate the help. Only thing is the first time it loads or when i do it in chrome, it actually loads the animation first and loads it again so it looks somewhat glitchy. Anyway to circumvent that?

Comment: @adeneo that's great. You should post your answer! :D

Comment: @bryan please refer to that: https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: @andre this isn't what I am referring to. the problem is with the animation going before I want it to or when I move the mouse. Not with loading the image.

Comment: I just used the animated gif as a starting image, you probably want a starting image of just a static line

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/yL5hbzxq/8/

Comment: @adeneo try that link on chrome, it's a tad glitchy when you un-hover :\

Comment: That's because you're using animated gifs

Comment: @adeneo is their an alternative to get the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the image is cached. Try adding some dynamic value at the end of the gif, like the time. Check the modifications I made at your code. I added current time at the img path.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#link-gif").hover(
        function() {
            /* starting animation */
            var url = "url('http://i.imgur.com/HhsBws5.gif?time=" + new Date().getTime() + "')";
            $(this).css("background-image", url);
        },
        function() {
            /* ending animation */
            var url = "url('http://i.imgur.com/WLFzz3S.gif?time=" + new Date().getTime() + "')";
console.log(url);
            $(this).css("background-image", url );
        }                         
    );                  
});
```

```css
#link-gif {
   width:150px;
   height:40px;
   border:1px solid #39464E;
   background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/YgLJoVH.png'); /*static*/
   background-size:contain;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:bottom center;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="link">
  <div id="link-gif">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```