# Prevent gif image from flickering during image change by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, gif

I am using the technique outlined in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733029/cross-browser-animated-gif-on-hover-reverse-when-mouse-leaves).

The problem is that we can notice that the image flashes during the transition between the 2 gif images. How can I prevent this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#link-gif").hover(function() {
    var url = "url('http://i.imgur.com/HhsBws5.gif?time=" + new Date().getTime() + "')";
    $(this).css("background-image", url);
  }, function() {
    var url = "url('http://i.imgur.com/WLFzz3S.gif?time=" + new Date().getTime() + "')";
    $(this).css("background-image", url);
  });
});
```

```css
#link-gif {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #39464E;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/YgLJoVH.png');
  /*static*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="link">
  <div id="link-gif">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd prepare two divs, one for each image, hide one and show the other with js, without bothering change the image. Pros: both images will be already downloaded (and probably also rendered), so the flickering will be near zero

Comment: The flash is caused due to the images loading. It happens every time as you include a date stamp in the image URL to prevent it from being cached. You need to pre-load the images.